# How do you release the wires from this Slater push-in connector?

Tags: electrical, wire

I know you are supposed to be able to push a screwdriver into a slot "under" the wire, but this old (late '70s?) Slater light switch has different slots than I see in all the examples.  They are more like recessed holes 1/4" square and are beside, not under the wire hole.

Am I supposed to push on the metal piece?  Do I need to get the screwdriver between the two pieces of metal I see at the bottom of the hole? something else?  I've tried pushing as hard as I can in different places but the wire doesn't seem to release.

[image: Slater Wire release slots]

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, but I usually just grab the wire with a pliers and spin the outlet while pulling. They basically screw right out.

Comment: Look at your photo: "Push to release".

Comment: DrMoishe Pippik Don't be an ass.  Read my post;  I've tried pushing as hard as I can in different places in the slot but the wire doesn't seem to release.

Comment: Yeah, just twist it out (back and forth about 270 degrees will suffice).  **Backstabs cannot be reused** regardless; once you jab a wire in there and use *any* method of releasing the spring, that spring is finished (permanent loss of clamping force).  There are 4 springs in a 50 cent outlet, what do you expect.   Also, never use backstabs *anyway* because they are notorious failure points.

Comment: Harper I'm not trying to reuse the switch, but good to know.  I'm trying to reuse the wire without having to cut it back.  I disagree with brute force to get it out, at least on these switches, that caused at least one wire to snap.  Who knows what damage that force is doing to the wire.

Comment: You push on the metal tab while pulling on the wire and it will come out. A piece of #12 copper wire makes a good pusher.

Comment: Why not just get a new one, you have gotten a fair amount of usage from it.